# How can I encrypt IP and port into a single number like kahoot does?

Tags: python, encryption, ip, port

I made a game which requires the client to connect to the server, the server IP however, changes constantly with each game session since one player is both the host(server) and a player(client). I think it would be cool if the host can just message a single number(maybe with ascii characters as well) which will have the IP and the port encrypted in it, a great example for what i want is kahoot, the host sends everyone a single number and everyone can connect. I am not looking for security, just an easy way to pass the IP and port. I am using python 2.7 but I just want an explanation on how to do this(although code will be very nice).

I want it to go something like this:

server:

```py
connection_code=encrypter(ip,port)
```

client:

```py
ip,port=decrypter(connection_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like Kahoot won't work if the client's communicate directly with each other. It would only work if you had one central server which keeps track of all servers or if all clients communicate with each other everytime a new server is available.

The reason for this is that you can't shrink the ip adress + port into a number with less digits that the ip + port itself, without providing extra information.

Comment: @עומרדודסון Without looking to much into it, i'd say no. My reasoning:
Compression only works if the string would be longer. Any traditional compression algorithm would inflate the size. 
So you'd need to substitute a sequence of digits with a character. There are only 93 characters in ascii that you could use and that includes the seperators (.:) and digits itself. Your basically shy of 10 or so characters to substitute 10-99 with letters.